# 'FILE' Input does not keep first selected element after second attempt (multiple files upload)

Tags: html, flask

I like to upload multiple files, so that I created an HTML file as below,

```
<label>Please upload text, image, or pdf file</label>
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="true" autocomplete="off" required>
```

I wrote an api using Flask and It works as intended. If I choose the files at first attempt, there is no problem it works. However, if I choose a file at first time and then I reattempt to put another file, the first uploaded file is overwritten by second file. In terms of back end side of my project, there is no problem, but on the client side, I could not able to upload files one by another due to overwrite problem.

**To visualize, this is my first attempt;**

[image: To visualize, this is my first attempt;]

**This is second attempt, it overwrites first upload;**

[image: This is second attempt]

**But if I want to upload them at one time, I can do it as below.**

[image: But if I want to upload them at one time, I can do it as below.]

I want to be able to add my files one by another. Is there any approach I can try?

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with the `multiple="true"` attribute.

> When the multiple Boolean attribute is specified, the file input allows the user to select more than one file.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Additional_attributes

If a user uploads a file(s), and then goes to upload again, doesn't it make sense that the first file is overwritten as you are experiencing? You can however do this through jQuery or AJAX file uploads.

[Try this one](https://www.dropzonejs.com/), or [this one](https://github.com/danielm/uploader/) which accomplishes what you want to achieve.